# JavaScript: Cut URL after nth slash

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have URLs like

```
http://www.domain.com/dir/dir2/dir3/dir4/#tag
```

or

```
http://www.domain.com/dir/dir2/dir3/dir4
```

Now I need to get only the url till dir3 and nothing after that… (or «everything till the sixth slash in the string»)

```
http://www.domain.com/dir/dir2/dir3/
```

How can this be accomblished with JavaScript?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need jQuery here, JavaScript supports Regular Expression:

```
"http://www.domain.com/dir/dir2/dir3/dir4".match(/([^/]*\/){6}/)[0]
```

A safer way is(in case of pattern mismatched):

```
function cutUrl(str) {
    var matched = str.match(/([^/]*\/){6}/);
    return matched ? matched[0] : str/* or null if you wish */;
}
```

Then call `cutUrl("http://www.domain.com/dir/dir2/dir3/dir4")`.

Comment: thx, I'm already using jquery … therefore jquery might be better than regex in sense of performance — am I right?

Comment: no, regex is built-in functionality, which should be efficient enough. Besides, jQuery is good at DOM, it has very few string-related function.

Comment: @albuvee  jQUery is a javascript library that uses native javascript methods wrapped in helper functions. Is always more performant to use native methods.

Comment: @charlietfl jopp, I knew that, but I thought RegEX is very performance-hungry …

Comment: Don't guess, just test. RegEx, esp. simple RegEx is fairly fast. Comparatively, using string/array's `split`/`join` will create many immediate objects, which should be more expensive.

Comment: @albuvee  over thinking the expense of parsing one string

Answer (score 7):

Try this:

```
'http://www.domain.com/dir/dir2/dir3/dir4/#tag'
  .split('/')
  .slice(0,6).join('/'));
 //=> http://www.domain.com/dir/dir2/dir3
```

or a helper function:

```
function cutUrl(url,n){
    return url.split('/').slice(0,n).join('/'));
}
```

Comment: This isn't really good since there can be multiple slashes in a url (safari does not cut them), therefore your code would get the wrong cut